# fail2ban txt list creation of banned IP

Tags: firewall, scripting, fail2ban, blacklist, import

using fail2ban for years, working nice, would like to automate and harden the security for my router.

So I would like that fail2ban created a local file, example, list.txt file with a list of banned IP addresses.

Something similar to this https://sslbl.abuse.ch/blacklist/sslipblacklist.txt

So I could share it on a webpage. My router is set up to import blocked IPs from such sources.

So how could I manage to do something like that? Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all banned ip with fail2ban?](https://serverfault.com/questions/841183/how-to-show-all-banned-ip-with-fail2ban)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can forexample add a function to an existing "action" located in     /etc/fail2ban/action.d/ , in my case I just added it into the "iptables-multiport.conf" file.

```
actionban = <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>
                echo '<ip>' >> /path/to/file/ips.txt
```

Comment: Added, restarted fail2ban but there is no file!

Comment: Can someone explain why above mentioned dose not work? Any other solution?

Comment: It could be everything to permission issues to a typo in your configuration.

Comment: So put the code as mentioned above                                                                   actionban = <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>
                echo '<ip>' >> /var/fail2ban/ip.txt  Permissions are like other files. Were to look, how to test? Can some one please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Orphan's answer is correct, but I will try to explain a little bit more.

**First, you should check which jail are you interested in, and then check which is the `actionban` associated to that jail.**

The `actionban` parameter can be traced in the config files of Fail2ban, but this is not necessarily straightforward. Take, for example, the following configuration in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[DEFAULT]
backend = auto
banaction = iptables-multiport
bantime = 1h

[sshd]
enabled = true
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
maxretry = 3
port = 22
```

For the `sshd` jail, no `banaction` is directly defined, so the default `banaction = iptables-multiport` is taken. Therefore, we should look into `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-multiport.conf` config file. If an `actionban` is not explicitly defined there, then we should check which file it refers to. In this example, the `iptables-multiport` config file includes:

```
[INCLUDES]

before = iptables.conf
```

This points to `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables.conf`, where we can finally find a definition for `actionban`:

```
actionban = <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>
```

Now, following Orphan's answer, it is possible to modify the ban action on this line, adding a custom command:

```
actionban = <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype>
            echo '<ip>'  >> /path/to/file/ips.txt
```

Finally, Fail2ban client should be reloaded in order to apply the changes:

```
fail2ban-client reload
```